# Connection pooling pattern

Tags: java, connection, connection-pooling, design-patterns, pool

How can I implement a connection pooling in Java?

There is some pattern?

I should use some connections and release it. This connection should be closed after a few times.

Comment: Why would you want to do it on your own? There are many existing solutions (eg. C3P0).

Comment: You can achieve this but you need to take care LOT of things for the same. Instead simply use ready made available APIs.

Comment: It's a simple solution, and I don't want to add more libraries.

Comment: @Victor it only seems simple at the beginning

Comment: Ok! There is no pattern! All happens by magic? Sorry, I know it's not simple, maybe I will use some library. But I want to know how to make a connection pooling!

Comment: Considering that there are several open-source connection pool libraries (commons-dbcp, c3p0) a good way to learn how one works might be to read the source code of the open-source projects. As for some advice: it's much more complicated than it sounds and 99% of the time you should use an established library rather than wasting time poorly reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use some libraries. For JDBC connection pooling check out [bonecp](/questions/tagged/bonecp), [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0) or [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp). If you need a general purpose pooling, see [commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/), which [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp) is built on.